# How to connect to remote server and start/stop the Tomcat that's running on that particular server using Ant?

Tags: java, xml, ant, jmx, cargo

### The purpose is to:

```
1: connect to a remote server maybe via host: ip , port: 8181
2: stop Tomcat that's running on that server 
3: deploy a .war file 
4: restart tomcat
```

Comment: When I want to do that, I use ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@hostname /home/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh; /home/tomcat/bin/startup.sh But I would love to see another technique to do that (ideally without requiring ssh)

Comment: Hello Guillaume Polet-  I was thinking of running start/stop ant command to start and stop tomcat, jboss etc. This is we can deploy let say one.war file to multiple servers with let say a single ant deploy-to-servers target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/index.html) under [Monitoring and Managing Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html) offers some information on how to stop a given application, but not the server entirely:

```
<jmx:invoke
    name="Catalina:type=Manager,path=/servlets-examples,host=localhost" 
    operation="stop"/>
```

If you have ssh access to the server, then you might like to consider the [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which you can use in combination with [SSHExec Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) to start and stop your server:

```
<sshexec host="somehost"
    username="dude"
    password="yo"
    command="/etc/init.d/tomcat restart"/>
```

Comment: I looked at your links, but I could not see where it explains how Tomcat can be started and stopped. But I may have just missed it.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet I think I may have missunderstood the question. The link I offered provides ways to start or stop a given application within Tomcat. I will correct my answer.

Comment: +1 for the sshexec + jsch notes. i like that a lot as routinely i get an out of memory error if i just use the `deploy` task. the deploy itself works ... i'm sure there's a tomcat jvm memory setting i need to tweak, but your option is a more than suitable alternate. nice!