# Execute a batch file on a remote PC using a batch file on local PC

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to execute a batch file

> D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin\shutdown.bat

Which is on my server `inidsoasrv01`.

How should I write my `.bat` file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute batch file on remote computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569893/execute-batch-file-on-remote-computer)

Comment: There are [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+run+script+on+remote+server)  about how to do this.

Comment: Although it really depends on how you connect to INIDSOASRV01 from your local PC. Do you use Remote Desktop? FTP? SSH? Telnet? Do you mount it as a network drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run script file on remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056573/run-script-file-on-remote-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to remote server and start/stop the Tomcat that's running on that particular server using Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432416/how-to-connect-to-remote-server-and-start-stop-the-tomcat-thats-running-on-that)

Answer (score 26):

Use microsoft's tool for remote commands executions: [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

If there isn't your bat-file on remote host, copy it first. For example:

```
copy D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin\shutdown.bat \\RemoteServerNameOrIP\d$\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin\
```

And then execute:

```
psexec \\RemoteServerNameOrIP d:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin\shutdown.bat
```

Note: filepath for psexec is path to file on remote server, not your local.

Comment: Why isn't this the top answer?! Thank you.

Comment: How to run the bat file from its own directory instead of running from C:\Windows\system32?

Comment: @FurqanSafdar i'd try to insert in a bat file `cd` command at the beginning, e.g.
d: & cd d:\path\

Answer (score 12):

You can use WMIC or SCHTASKS (which means no third party software is needed):

1. [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html):

   SCHTASKS /s remote_machine /U username /P password /create /tn "On demand demo" /tr "C:\some.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
   SCHTASKS /s remote_machine /U username /P password /run /TN "On demand demo"
2. [WMIC](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) (wmic will return the pid of the started process)

   WMIC /NODE:"remote_machine" /user:user /password:password process call create "c:\some.bat","c:\exec_dir"

Comment: I am also involved in the similar type of task 
I am getting 
ERROR:
Description = Access is denied.
ON Executing below command from a PC 'A' command line to execute a batch file on a PC 'B' (100-SER) 

WMIC /user:100 /password:nspl /node:"100-SER" process call create "cmd.exe /c c:\erp\qrgen.bat"

Comment: @Azad - try to execute these as admin.

Comment: @npocmaka Same issue

Comment: The correct command will be : WMIC /NODE:"remote_machine" /user:user /password:password process call create "c:\some.bat","c:\exec_dir"

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you are in same WORKGROUP `shutdown.exe /s /m \\<target-computer-name>` should be enough `shutdown /?` for more, otherwise</strike> you need software to connect and control the target server.

**UPDATE:**

Seems shutdown.bat here is for shutting down apache-tomcat.

So, you might be interested to [psexec](https://serverfault.com/a/168421)  or [PuTTY: A Free Telnet/SSH Client](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

As native solution could be `wmic`

Example:

`wmic /node:<target-computer-name> process call create "cmd.exe c:\\somefolder\\batch.bat"`

In your example should be:

```
wmic /node:inidsoasrv01 process call create ^
    "cmd.exe D:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\\bin\\shutdown.bat"
```

`wmic /?` and `wmic /node /?` for more

Answer (score 0):

With all the new security updates from Microsoft in the latest operating systems it is becoming more and more difficult to connect and execute scripts remotely. PsExec is one tool that helps you to connect a windows host from another windows host and execute command(s) or a script. Limitation of this tool is that it will execute the command(s) or a script, but it will not print the execution details. It will only return the process id.

```
C:\apps\tools\psexec \\%RemoteHostName% -u %Domain%\%userName% -p %userPassword% -accepteula -d -h -i 1 cmd.exe /c "cd C:\apps\test\ & echo Hello World" & call C:\apps\test\script.bat
```

Answer (score -2):

While I would recommend against this.

But you can use shutdown as client if the target machine has remote shutdown enabled and is in the same workgroup.

Example:

```
shutdown.exe /s /m \\<target-computer-name> /t 00
```

replacing `<target-computer-name>` with the URI for the target machine,

Otherwise, if you want to trigger this through Apache, you'll need to configure the batch script as a CGI script by putting `AddHandler cgi-script .bat` and `Options +ExecCGI` into either a local `.htaccess` file or in the main configuration for your Apache install.

Then you can just call the `.bat` file containing the `shutdown.exe` command from your browser.

Comment: This doesn't address the overall question of how to run a remote batch file  from a separate computer.

Comment: Tomcat's shutdown.bat file is for properly shutting down Tomcat, not the whole server.