# How to execute a bat file on remote machine from another web app

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io, remote-server

We  have a custom deployment application just like the jenkins written in java , we will used it to push new codes into the Test server. and we have our TestNg automation running on another remote machine .now its run by a scheduled task on windows machine.this task will trigger a bat file , which will execute the TestNg script.

How can i call the bat file used for running the TestNg script from the custom deployment application  ?

how this can be archived using Java or node js

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482483/how-to-execute-a-batch-file-on-a-remote-pc-using-a-batch-file-on-local-pc

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a task to run a .bat file. In this .bat file:
1. Push the code to the test server
2. After that run the TestNG script
Just like below:

```
@echo off
REM start script to push code to test server
start /wait "" "script1.exe"
REM start script to run TestNG
start "" "script2.exe"
```

Comment: No we want to run Automation whenever there is a new code change,so this Solutions won’t works